# Security Vulnerabilities in IoT enabled Medical Device

Tags: security, iot, health-monitoring, medical

Looking for some idea on security related to medical devices.. like there can be OEM(s) who manufacture the devices or can be hospitals buying it out from different vendors for setting up their infrastructure. How do we really identify whether a device is IoT enabled and security assesment needs to be done. Like example, if we look at Johnson & Johnson or Baxter .. they build medical devices but how do we know it's an IoT and related security to be addressed. Any kind of information and guidance would be of great help. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a huge topic.

Comment: While is an important subject matter, it utterly fails to fit within the Stack Exchange requirement for *specificity* and so cannot be handled here.  Additionally, this is **off topic** on Stackoverflow as it is a *usage* question and not a *software development* question.

Answer (score -1):

I would take a look at alibaba as many companies source china for manufacturing. Typically knock offs will occur(or its just plain OEM'ed from china) and will prob show up on places like alibaba. Within the listings of alibaba you can see if they list or you can email the supplier and ask if they use dhawa,  hisilicon or any of the other IoT boards in their product.